# plotting time series in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am working with data, 1st two columns are dates, 3rd column is symbol, and 4th and 5th columns are prices.
So, I created a subset of the data as follows:

```
test.sub<-subset(test,V3=="GOOG",select=c(V1,V4)
```

and then I try to plot a time series chart using the following

```
as.ts(test.sub)
plot(test.sub)
```

well, it gives me a scatter plot - not what I was looking for.
so, I tried `plot(test.sub[1],test.sub[2])`
and now I get the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

To make sure the no. of rows were same, I ran `nrow(test.sub[1])` and `nrow(test.sub[2])` and they both return equal rows, so as a newcomer to R, I am not sure what the fix is.

I also ran `plot.ts(test.sub)` and that works, but it doesn't show me the dates in the x-axis, which it was doing with `plot(test.sub)` and which is what I would like to see.

```
test.sub[1]
              V1
1107 2011-Aug-24
1206 2011-Aug-25
1307 2011-Aug-26
1408 2011-Aug-29
1510 2011-Aug-30
1613 2011-Aug-31
1718 2011-Sep-01
1823 2011-Sep-02
1929 2011-Sep-06
2035 2011-Sep-07
2143 2011-Sep-08
2251 2011-Sep-09
2359 2011-Sep-13
2470 2011-Sep-14
2581 2011-Sep-15
2692 2011-Sep-16
2785 2011-Sep-19
2869 2011-Sep-20
2965 2011-Sep-21
3062 2011-Sep-22
3160 2011-Sep-23
3258 2011-Sep-26
3356 2011-Sep-27
3455 2011-Sep-28
3555 2011-Sep-29
3655 2011-Sep-30
3755 2011-Oct-03
3856 2011-Oct-04
3957 2011-Oct-05
4059 2011-Oct-06
4164 2011-Oct-07
4269 2011-Oct-10
4374 2011-Oct-11
4479 2011-Oct-12
4584 2011-Oct-13
4689 2011-Oct-14

str(test.sub)
'data.frame':   35 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1:Class 'Date'  num [1:35] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ V4: num  0.475 0.452 0.423 0.418 0.403 ...

head(test.sub) V1 V4 
1212 <NA> 0.474697 
1313 <NA> 0.451907 
1414 <NA> 0.423184 
1516 <NA> 0.417709 
1620 <NA> 0.402966 
1725 <NA> 0.414264
```

Now that this is working, I'd like to add a 3rd variable to plot a 3d chart - any suggestions how I can do that. thx!

Comment: What kind of plot are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: just a line graph with the x-axis showing the dates in 1st column and y-axis showing the prices in 4th column

Comment: Then just do `plot(test.sub,type="l")`.

Comment: it still gives me scatter points as with `plot(test.sub)`.

Comment: also, as a beginner, I am keen to understand why I get the `Error in xy.coords` when the number of rows in both the columns are the same

Comment: Well, I believe that `test.sub` is a data frame, so I suspect you mean `plot(test.sub[,1],test.sub[,2])`.  Using `type="l"` in the `plot` function gives you a line graph instead of a scatter plot.

Comment: In you code you are missing an assignment: try this, `test.sub <- as.tx(test.sub)`.

Comment: yes it is a data frame, and I was writing sub[1], not sub[,1], so I corrected that. I wish there was a way I could show the result of the type="l". If I run `plot.ts(test.sub)`, it shows me a line graph, but unfortunately not with `type="l"`

Comment: it couldn't find function `as.tx`

Comment: @RYogi I doubt that is what is really needed. If `V1` and `V4` do not contain any temporal information you are better off using standard R plotting, and if they do, you are probably better off getting that temporal information into something R can understand and still stick with R's standard plotting. (I.e. not the ts methods.) Either way, simple coercion to class "ts" without setting the time series properties isn't much use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I think there are a few things going on here that are worth talking through:

first, some example data:

```
test <- data.frame(End = Sys.Date()+1:5, 
               Start = Sys.Date()+0:4, 
               tck = rep("GOOG",5), 
               EndP= 1:5, 
               StartP= 0:4)

test.sub = subset(test, tck=="GOOG",select = c(End, EndP))
```

First, note that test and test.sub are both data frames, so calls like `test.sub[1]` don't really "mean" anything to R.** It's more R-ish to write `test.sub[,1]` by virtue of consistency with other R structures. If you compare the results of `str(test.sub[1])` and `str(test.sub[,1])` you'll see that R treats them slightly differently.

You said you typed:

```
as.ts(test.sub)
plot(test.sub)
```

I'd guess you have extensive experience with some sort of OO-language; and while R does have some OO flavor to it, it doesn't apply here. Rather than transforming test.sub to something of class ts, this just does the transformation and throws it away, then moves on to plot the data frame you started with. It's an easy fix though:

```
test.sub.ts <- as.ts(test.sub)
plot(test.sub.ts)
```

But, this probably isn't what you were looking for either. Rather, R creates a time series that has two variables called "End" (which is the date now coerced to an integer) and "EndP". Funny business like this is part of the reason time series packages like zoo and xts have caught on so I'll detail them instead a little further down.

(Unfortunately, to the best of my understanding, R doesn't keep date stamps with its default ts class, choosing instead to keep start and end dates as well as a frequency. For more general time series work, this is rarely flexible enough)

You could perhaps get what you wanted by typing

```
plot(test.sub[,1], test.sub[,2])
```

instead of

```
plot(test.sub[1], test.sub[2])
```

since the former runs into trouble given that you are passing two sub-data frames instead of two vectors (even though it looks like you would be).***

Anyways, with xts (and similarly for zoo):

```
library(xts) # You may need to install this
xtemp <- xts(test.sub[,2], test.sub[,1]) # Create the xts object
plot(xtemp) 
# Dispatches a xts plot method which does all sorts of nice time series things
```

Hope some of this helps and sorry for the inline code that's not identified as such: still getting used to stack overflow.

Michael

**In reality, they access the lists that are used to structure a data frame internally, but that's more a code nuance than something worth relying on.

***The nitty-gritty is that when you pass `plot(test.sub[1], test.sub[2])` to R, it dispatches the method `plot.data.frame` which takes a single data frame and tries to interpret the second data frame as an additional plot parameter which gets misinterpreted somewhere way down the line, giving your error.

Comment: thanks for the explanation - indeed very helpful. ran into a glitch with xts. I ran the following `xtemp<-xts(test.sub[,2],test.sub[,1])
Error in xts(test.sub[, 2], test.sub[, 1]) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object` I checked `test.sub[1]` and it shows the dates in format 'yyyy-mmm-dd' so it is a time-based object...have I missed something

Comment: If it shows the dates as "yyyy-mm-dd" it's not necessarily a time based object: depending on your data source it may just be a character that to you is obviously a date, but R doesn't know that. A Date is a special data type to R...Try wrapping test.sub[,1] with as.Date() which takes an optional format= argument if your not following the standard. For you, it sounds like as.Date(test.sub[,1], format = "YYYY-mm-dd") will work.

Comment: tried that, but no luck, here's what it returns - `as.Date(test.sub[,1],format="YYYY-mm-dd")
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[26] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`. this is a sample of my data in test.sub `4689 2011-Oct-14 0.2460010 7.18000 1.000000` with the date being V1

Comment: @itcplpl I believe mweylandt just gave you the wrong format for the format argument (irony!). Try `format = '%Y-%m-%d'` instead.

Comment: that returned NA's as well :-( this is what I got `as.Date(test.sub[,1],format='%Y-%m-%d')
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[26] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
`

Comment: So it took me a bit to figure this out, but it looks like this is the right syntax: sorry, I missed that you had your month recorded as a character: as.Date("2011-Oct-18", format = "%Y-%b-%d") Don't ask me why %b is the correct code, it just seems to work...

Comment: The as.Date() function uses the same format characters that strptime() does, so ?strptime will help for interpreting '%Y-%b-%d' or adapting to other formats.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you get the Error about different `x` and `y` lengths is immediately apparent if you do a traceback immediately upon raising the error:

```
> plot(test.sub[1],test.sub[2])
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
> traceback()
6: stop("'x' and 'y' lengths differ")
5: xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log)
4: plot.default(x1, ...)
3: plot(x1, ...)
2: plot.data.frame(test.sub[1], test.sub[2])
1: plot(test.sub[1], test.sub[2])
```

The problems in your call are manifold. First, as mentioned by @mweylandt `test.sub[1]` is a data frame with the single component, not a vector comprised of the contents of the first component of `test.sub`.

From the traceback, we see that the `plot.data.frame` method was called. R is quite happy to plot a data frame as long as it has at least two columns. R took you at your word and passed `test.sub[1]` (as a data.frame) on to `plot()` - `test.sub[2]` never gets a look in. `test.sub[1]` is eventually passed on to `xy.coords()` which correctly informs you that you have lots of rows for `x` but 0 rows for `y` because `test.sub[1]` only contains a single component.

It would have worked if you'd done `plot(test.sub[,1], test.sub[,2], type = "l")` or used the formula interface to name the variables `plot(V4 ~ V1, data = test.sub, type = "l")` as I show in my other Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Surely it is easier to use the formula interface:

```
> test <- data.frame(End = Sys.Date()+1:5, 
+                Start = Sys.Date()+0:4, 
+                tck = rep("GOOG",5), 
+                EndP= 1:5, 
+                StartP= 0:4)
> 
> test.sub = subset(test, tck=="GOOG",select = c(End, EndP))
> head(test.sub)
         End EndP
1 2011-10-19    1
2 2011-10-20    2
3 2011-10-21    3
4 2011-10-22    4
5 2011-10-23    5
> plot(EndP ~ End, data = test.sub, type = "l")
```

I work extensively with time series type data and rarely, if ever, have any need for the `"ts"` class of objects. Packages **zoo** and **xts** are very useful, but if all you want to do is plot the data, i) get the date/time information correctly formatted/set-up as a `"Date"` or `"POSIXt"` class object, and then ii) just plot it using standard graphics and `type = "l"` (or `type = "b"` or `type = "o"` if you want to see the observation times).

Comment: thanks for the example, that is helpful. my issue right now is with getting the Date class object to work correctly. I can't use `Sys.Date()` as I am dealing with historical data. I posted the error I am getting with Date..a suggestion on the fix would be very helpful

Comment: @itcplpl How about you **show** us what your date data look like? If you show me the format I'll show you how to convert that into something R can read.

Comment: sounds good. I just updated the original post with the date data

Comment: @itcplpl `test.sub <- within(test.sub, V1 <- as.Date(V1, format = "Y%-%b-%d"))` should do it. See `?strftime` for details of the format codes.

Comment: thanks for the pointer on strftime. that bit worked but when I ran the plot, it gives me an error...here's what I ran `test.sub<-within(test.sub, V1<-as.Date(V1, format = "%Y-%b-%d"))
> xtemp<-xts(test.sub[,2],test.sub[,1])
> plot(xtemp)
Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
`

Comment: I ran `head(test.sub)` and I get: `head(test.sub)
       V1       V4 
1212 <NA> 0.474697 
1313 <NA> 0.451907 
1414 <NA> 0.423184 
1516 <NA> 0.417709 
1620 <NA> 0.402966 
1725 <NA> 0.414264 
`

Comment: @itcplpl I didn't tell you to use **xts**. Try `head(test.sub)` and `str(test.sub)` to see if the dates are encode correctly. It works for me with the dummy data I used above, converted to an **xts** object and plotted.

Comment: @itcplpl Please stop posting R output here - it is unreadable - add it to your Q as you did your data. Basically your `test.sub` doesn't look like it has any valid dates in it and you have <NA> so I suspect a factor is involved here.

Comment: ok, I just cleaned up everything and re-ran all the commands and now it works...the date worked. I don't understand what the error was but I am glad it's working. so, for the graph, now I am using `plot(test.sub,type="l")`. thanks a bunch for your help :-). Since you work extensively with time series type data, would you have any suggestions for plotting 3d graphs - time vs. price1 vs. price2

Comment: @itcplpl I would plot the data using trellising or faceting as per lattice or ggplot graphics. If I wanted and price1 and price2 had similar comparable ranges, I would plot both series on the same plot. For that, issue `plot.new()` between plot calls and you need to draw separate axes by hand via the `axis()` function. If you need more help, search on SO and ask a Q if there is nothing there already.

Comment: ok, will do so. I was looking up lattice but I think it needs me to format my data differently....I'll check on it and ask the Q on SO